# LEFT JOIN with AND operator using Criteria API

Tags: sql, jpa, predicate, criteria-api

I am trying to build dynamic queries using JPA and Criteria API but without metamodels.

With the tables:

```
Foo:
ID
1
2
3
4
```

---

```
Bar: 
ID   FooID   Number
1    2       44
2    2       55
3    3       55
```

I want to retrieve all Foo entities where no matching Bar has Number 44. (Expecting Foo 1, 3, 4)

The SQL should look something like this:

```
select distinct *
from Foo foo0_
left join Bar bar0_ on foo0_.ID=bar0_.FooID and bar0_.Number=44
where bar0__.id is null;
```

My code looks something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Foo> cq = cb.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> fooRoot = cq.from(Foo.class);
cq.select(fooRoot).distinct(true);

List<Predicate> allPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
List<Predicate> orPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
List<Predicate> andPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
andPredicates.add(cb.equal(fooRoot.join("bars", JoinType.LEFT).get("number"), 44));
andPredicates.add(cb.isNull(fooRoot.join("bars", JoinType.LEFT).get("ID")));
orPredicates.add(cb.and(andPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[andPredicates.size()])));
allPredicates.add(cb.or(orPredicates.toArray(newPredicate[orPredicates.size()])));

cq.where(allPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[allPredicates.size()]));
TypedQuery<Foo> query = em.createQuery(cq);
query.getResultList();
```

But that generates this SQL:

```
select distinct *
from Foo foo0_
left outer join Bar bar1_ on foo0_.id=bar1_.FooID
left outer join Bar bar2_ on foo0_.id=bar2_.FooID
where bar1_.Number=44 and (bar2_.id is null);
```

and returns no Foo.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't specify which JPA implementation this is for, and clearly the SQL may differ for each.

That aside, your joining is wrong. Each `join` call will do a JOIN, and you only want 1 join if what you write is correct. Also you can make use of JPA 2.1 "ON" conditions on the join (rather than putting it in the WHERE).

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Foo> cq = cb.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> fooRoot = cq.from(Foo.class);
cq.select(fooRoot).distinct(true);

Join barJoin = fooRoot.join("bars", JoinType.LEFT);
Predicate onCond = cb.equal(barJoin.get("number"), 44);
barJoin.on(onCond);
```

Then do the same as your question except using the `barJoin`; no idea what those AND/OR conditions are trying to do - your suggested SQL has none of that.

Comment: I use Hibernate JPA 2.0 so unfortunately barJoin.on(onCond) doesn't work. The _and_, _or_ and _all_ predicates are for building dynamic queries on different tables and with different parameters.

Comment: Changed to JPA 2.1 and used your code but changed qb to cb and I get AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.ListAttributeJoin.on(Ljavax/persistence/criteria/Expression;)Ljavax/persistence/criteria/join; Is qb a QueryBuilder and do I need one? Can't find it in the JPA dependency.

Comment: Yes, you metioned JPA 2.1 "ON" conditions and I "Changed to JPA 2.1" because I want to do it the right way but I can't get it to work. What is qb?

Comment: Yes, "qb" should be "cb" (now updated) and Join quite clearly has an "on" method taking Predicate or Expression. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Join.html